# Recover lost python code from running script?

Tags: ipython

I am a bit panicked right now, and I hope someone can help.  I spent months writing a python program on Notepad++.  The final bugs were finally worked out and the script was launched in ipython via PowerShell.  Right when I went to push the save button in Notepad++, the program crashed, and when it recovered, all of the code was missing.  It is as if I deleted all of the code and then hit save.

The python code is still running, and it should for several more hours.  My question: is there a way to recover the code by interrupting the running script and somehow accessing the code from ipython?  It always shows several lines of the code in ipython when the script is broken, and I am hoping I can somehow recover the full code through this.

Comment: You wrote a program over a few months, and didn't make a single backup of it?

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://buffernow.com/notepad-plus-crash-recover-your-lost-file/)

If that doesn't work, let it be a lesson to ALWAYS back up your work. Use GitHub

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I tried, but there is not a Notebook++ cache that I could locate.  There must be a way to list the script that is being used in iPython's memory.  I am watching the code work now, so it has to be in a cache somewhere?  Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!